# detect certain value in style attribute and change it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought the following code would work for my needs

`$("td[style='background-color: #FFBBBB']").css('background-color', '#333');`

but the problem I am facing is that each `td` has different values within the `style` attribute for instance:

`font-weight: normal;background-color:#FFBBBB;` and the code above doesn't seem to execute since there are multiple values. How can I account for this?

Essentially I want to change elements with the background color of `#FFBBBB` to another color.

Comment: Any chance you can put these styles in a class and use a stylesheet? Then you can use the css class selector.

Comment: Use classes in the first place to _give_ those elements that background color – then you will only have to filter/select elements by that class, and that’s much easier and straight-forward.

Comment: @CBroe I'm at the mercy of a pretty poor plain HTML API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing [Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("td[style*=#FFBBBB]").css("background-color", "#333");
```

Comment: Huh, that worked! I did in fact try it with an asterisks but it didn't work. Any reason why you left out `background-color`?

Comment: @Katie _"Any reason why you left out background-color"_ Not certain if space character appeared at `html` between `background-color:`  property and value `#FFBBBB` ? See `$("td[style='background-color: #FFBBBB']")` , `font-weight: normal;background-color:#FFBBBB;` at Question

Comment: Generally browsers auto-format the style attribute to have spaces between the colon and the value, but that would not be something to rely on. The best solution is still to use css classes.